# Can I use CloneZilla over ssh?

Tags: ssh, backup, clonezilla

I regularly use CloneZilla from a live CD for image backups of the (Windows-) machines in our small LAN, writing the images to a Samba file server. This works fine but requires me to not only to walk to the machine to boot from the CD and start the backup but also to visually check whether the backup is done or still running.

I am used to doing Linux administration over ssh so I would really like to also just put the CD into the drive, let the computer boot and do everything else over an ssh connection.

Is that possible?

(This is not about storing/loading an image to/from an ssh server! I know how to do that but it does not answer the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CloneZilla's [builtin SSH server](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/05_Started_with_sshd_on_and_passwd_assigned) to remote control / run the process unattended.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Something else I just found which might be usefull for others: Automated Windows partition backup\restore boot menu using CloneZilla http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/clonezilla